# Can't get the value of an element

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to get the value of an input element. The element is in a modal and the modal data is populated with different values depending on the button I click to open the modal.

```
var modalBody = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body");
for(var i = 0; i < modalbody.length; i++) {
    var mac = modalBody.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div')[2].getElementById("mac-name").value;
    alert(mac);
}
```

> error: TypeError:
>   modalBody.item(...).getElementsByTagName(...)[2].getElementById is not
>   a function

I also tried with `document.getElementById("mac-name").value;` but that returns **blank**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="station-name" class="col-form-label">ID:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="station-id" name="edit--id" required="" type="text" hidden="">
            <input class="form-control" id="station-name" name="edit--name" required="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="profile-name" class="col-form-label">Profile:</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="profile-name" name="edit-profile" required="">
            <option>name1</option>
            <option>name2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mac-name" class="col-form-label">MAC Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="mac-name" name="edit-mac" required="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `getElementsByClassName` and then running the following on each element:

```
var mac = modalBody.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div')[2].getElementById("mac-name").value;
```

You can use instead use `querySelectorAll` and pass in `.modal-body div #mac-name`. This will select all elements with the id `mac-name` inside a `div` within an element with the class `modal-body`. You can use the results of this to then loop over each element and get each value:

```
var macs = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body div #mac-name');
```

See example below:

```js
var macs = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body div #mac-name');
for (var i = 0; i <  macs.length; i++) {
  var mac = macs[i].value;
  console.log(mac);
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="station-name" class="col-form-label">ID:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="station-id1" name="edit--id" required="" type="text" hidden="">
      <input class="form-control" id="station-name1" name="edit--name" required="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="profile-name" class="col-form-label">Profile:</label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="profile-name1" name="edit-profile" required="">
        <option>name1</option>
        <option>name2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mac-name" class="col-form-label">MAC Address:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="mac-name" name="edit-mac" value="Addr 1" required="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="station-name" class="col-form-label">ID:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="station-id2" name="edit--id" required="" type="text" hidden="">
      <input class="form-control" id="station-name2" name="edit--name" required="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="profile-name" class="col-form-label">Profile:</label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="profile-name2" name="edit-profile" required="">
        <option>name1</option>
        <option>name2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mac-name" class="col-form-label">MAC Address:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="mac-name" name="edit-mac" value="Addr 2" required="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I am getting strange results. When I load the page I still get no mac but if i refresh the page I get a mac. Even when I get the mac though, it only gives me the mac for the first modal in the list. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Are the modals already on the page when it loads or do you need to open them (ie are they added to the page dynamically?)

Comment: Also, your website shouldn't have multiple elements with the id of `mac-name`. It is considered invalid html as `id`'s should be unique to the element. Maybe make sure the input boxes have text in them when your running your script

Comment: In the above example, I also added an additional modal body and it seems to be working fine for me as it gets both macs

Comment: There is one modal on the page and the modal data is loaded when I open a click a button to open the modal. It loads with different data depending on which button i click. I guess i need to get the mac after i have click the button to load the modal.

Comment: @Gary yeah, since the content isn't on the page (ie the new modal doesn't exist yet) the above code won't retrieve it if it is fired before the new modal is added to the page. Running it after you click the button to load the modal might not work either since your code will most likely run a few milliseconds before the new modal is added, and thus you'll have the same issue. I recommend looking into maybe using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which allows you to check for changes on particular elements (such as if an element was added)